# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS freezes few times per hour and very unstable

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, freeze, crash

Title show the problem, it is brand-new install, so I don't think it should happen, while the install I selected minimal install because I don't need libreoffice things, and after install I only installed gpart, testdisk, edge beta, htop and discord.
on the fresh install(no thing installed and even on install disc) it still crash or freeze for few times, also something that require login make session crash like discord and the online accounts in settings. 
By the way, the os also have some weird render issue, sometimes when I watching youtube it render some weird block and snow thing on screen.
Also I saw htop(resource moniter) showing memory spike(use up all memory) when something freezes the system.
Also, I could not terminate the session using ctrl alt backspace when freezing, only thing works is alt sysrq b.
**note 'freeze' meaning mouse not work, keybroad work, speaker sometimes work, screen freeze.*

```
System info:
Hardware Model: ASUSTeK Computer INC. BM6835_BM6635_BP6335
Ram: dual 8GiB ddr3
GPU: GTX650ti boost
CPU: Intel® Core™ i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz × 8
Drive: 1t total | 255MiB efi | 128GiBext4 ubuntu | 803GiB ntfs storage |
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, 64bit, GNOME V42.2, Windowing System: Wayland
```

Edit: I see the graphics in about/settings, it show NVE6?

Comment: During the install, did you allow Ubuntu to download additional drivers your system might need? Also, 22.04 uses Snap, which downloads updates without asking user permission., Try removing Snap, https://haydenjames.io/remove-snap-ubuntu-22-04-lts/

Comment: @DrMoishePippik thank you for replying, I remember I allowed it to download driver, and okay I will try remove snap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked on askubuntu, answer is because I don't have graphic driver and Wayland support is bad for nvidia gpu.
[askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1443251/ubuntu-22-04-1-lts-freezes-few-times-per-hour-and-very-unstable?)

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome can cause this. Seems to be cos Hardware Acceleration is enabled.
Other users have reported using Firefox the system runs without problem.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had this excat problem, ubuntu was freezing every 15mins and not working till I restart it or using `REISUB` I've tried literally every single solution offered in the internet, Youtube videos, Reddit Answers, Superusers, Ask Ubuntu, some people said it's caused by the graphics driver, some people said it's caused by the BIOS, but lastly I ran ubuntu on kernel `6.2.0-26-generic` and now the problem fixed, and my ubuntu didn't freeze since.